# Centralizers of elements of a normal subgroup of a finite group in GAP

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, gap

Let $G$ be a finite group and $N$ be a normal subgroup of it. I need a command in GAP to list centralizers of elements of $N$ in $G$ which are distinct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`List(Set(N, x -> Centralizer(G, x)));`

Comment: Thanks - actually, `List` is not needed, just `Set(N, x -> Centralizer(G, x))` suffices.

Comment: @AlexanderKonovalov Thank you for your comment. I just added `List` because of the ambiguity of what "list centralizers" means. By the way, is such usage of `Set` documented in the manual? I cannot find it somehow.

Comment: Ah indeed, it's not documented, although a colleague told me today that this usage is there for some time. As for the "to list centralisers... which are distinct", I understand that as "to produce a list of distinct centralisers", that is, what `Set` already returns.